# Creating orderBy expression that runs a function in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, function, expression, sql-order-by, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of people with `firstName`s and `lastName`s. I'm want to `ng-repeat` through the them and then `orderBy: 'lastName'`. This works fine.

However, some `person`s in my `people` array only have a first name. I want to be able to order by the last name, and whenever it finds someone with a *only* a first name, to treat that first name as a last name, ie. the initial of the first name is alphabetised with the rest of the last names (hope that makes sense...)

Is it a case of writing a function in my controller and then calling that variable in the `orderBy:` expression? I've tried that and it didn't work:

Controller:

```
self.nameOrder = function(thisOne) {
    if (thisOne.lastName == null) {
        thisOne.firstName == thisOne.lastName;
    }
}
```

View:

```
<p ng-repeat="name in people | orderBy: 'lastName.nameOrder()' ">{{lastName}}</p>
```

I'm aware the above is probably totally wrong, but I thought it better to at least show what I've been attempting so it's clearer what my intentions are :/

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the code that generates the array that you are ordering. Also note that Angular orderBy will only order arrays so if you're not using an array it will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is supposed to be a getter, i.e. to return a value that `orderBy` will use to compare all the users with each other.

Your function doesn't return anything. Moreover, you're not passing the function as argument to `orderBy`. The code should be:

```
self.nameOrder = function(thisOne) {
    // return lastName, or firstName if lastName is null
    return thisOne.lastName || thisOne.firstName;
}
```

and the html should use

```
ng-repeat="name in people | orderBy:vm.nameOrder"
```

(assuming `vm` is the alias used for your controller)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the problem is with:

```
thisOne.firstName == thisOne.lastName;
```

That line should be:

```
thisOne.firstName = thisOne.lastName;
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue with the function not returning any value and doesn't make the code work.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I wanted to upvote your answer, but I went below 16 probably because of your downwote :D Also, I wanted to post my answer as a comment not an answer, but I couldn't.